# How to use NSLineSeparatorCharacter and NSParagraphSeparatorCharacter?

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, paragraph, line-breaks, nscharacterset

I wonder how I can use the constants `NSLineSeparatorCharacter` and `NSParagraphSeparatorCharacter` as a parameter to a function instead of hard coding `\n`.

```
- (id)initWithSeparator:(id)separator {
 m_separator = separator;
}
```

What would be the correct parameter type and what conversion needs to be done?
Depending on the file contents I wish to call the function like ...

```
Object* obj = [[Object alloc] initWithSeparator:NSLineSeparatorCharacter];
```

... or ...

```
Object* obj = [[Object alloc] initWithSeparator:NSParagraphSeparatorCharacter];
```

Apples [String Programming Guide / Paragraphs and Line Breaks](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/stringsParagraphBreaks.html) was not helpful, though.

Answer (score 0):

The correct parameter type would be unichar - no need to convert anything? If you want to create an NSString later, you'll have to use something like

```
    unichar myChar = NSParagraphSeparatorCharacter;
    NSString *myString = [NSString stringWithCharacters:&myChar length:1];
```